# Post data to Server JSON

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

Class : Time

```
public class Time {

public int LPassIN;
public int LPassOUT;
int secondPassed = 0;
Timer mytime = new Timer();
String PPassIN = Integer.toString(LPassIN);
String PPassOUT = Integer.toString(LPassOUT);

Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

ServerI serv = new ServerI(PPassIN,PPassOUT,responseListener);
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Time.this);





TimerTask mytask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        secondPassed++;


        if (secondPassed == 11) {
            secondPassed = 0;

            Convertion callConvertion = new Convertion();
            try {
                callConvertion.cnvrt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int donecnvrtin = callConvertion.donecnvrtin();
            int donecnvrtout = callConvertion.donecnvrtout();

            if (LPassIN != donecnvrtin) {
                LPassIN = donecnvrtin;
                queue.add(serv);
                System.out.println(LPassIN);
            }

            if (LPassOUT != donecnvrtout) {
                LPassOUT = donecnvrtout;
                queue.add(serv);
                System.out.println(LPassOUT);
            }

        } else {

            System.out.println("Second : " + secondPassed);
        }
    }
};
```

Class : ServerI

```
public class ServerI extends StringRequest {


private static final String UPLOAD_URL="http://userfb.esy.es/serverInteraction.php";
public Map<String,String> params;


public ServerI(String PPassIN,String PPassOUT,Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST,UPLOAD_URL,listener,null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("PPassIN",PPassIN);
    params.put("PPassOUT",PPassOUT);
}

@Override
public Map<String,String> getParams(){
    return params;
 }


}
```

PHP code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("\", "\", "\", "\");

$PPassIN = $_POST["PPassIN"];
$PPassOUT = $_POST["PPassOUT"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO Count(PassIN,PassOUT) VALUES (?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss", $PPassIN, $PPassOUT):
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
$response ["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Help me please, I'm trying to post data to server/database MySQL every 10 seconds,the data were derived from other class

this is a background service

so how to do it? is it my concept wrong? 
my service crash when started

Comment: What is your error in your logcat?

Comment: i cant convert Time into Context,so extends the Context then the app cant start.. extends AppCompatActivity also crash

Comment: There is a area in Android Studio called logcat which shows log(s) and error(s) when you debug your app. It should be at the bottom of Android Studio. What I want to know is the exception message displayed in the logcat.

Comment: Error:(39, 53) error: incompatible types: Time cannot be converted to Context
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
Incremental compilation of 3 classes completed in 0.114 secs.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: `Compilation failed`. So there is no app yet. Apps run on your Android device. But this error is generated by the compiler on your pc. Dont say that your app will not start or your service crashes if there even is no app. Your code will not compile. That is the problem.